# Importing root CA or the intermediate CA instead of the individual public cert

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, truststore

SSL certs never ends to dazzle me. I have an web-app and it makes a rest call to another service from a partner to fetch certain data. They use a self sign'ed or an internal CA generated for the Company. The issue is whenever the other end updates there SSL cert, my app fails. This is because the public cert (.cer) that i downloaded from their website and imported in the java trustore of my app doesn't match with their new site. To fix this, i have to re-download their latest public server cert and import again to my java trust store.

Assuming that they use a consistent ROOT CA or an intermediate CA cert to sign their ever changing SSL certs, can i just import the ROOT CA or the INTERMEDIATE CA once and for in my java trust store all to deal with this? So, as long as they don't change the ROOT CA or the INTERMEDIATE CA, my app will be able to make the call.

Answer (score 0):

So their self signed CERT is not built from ROOT CA.  Their CERT they generated themselves, so that is why it is considered untrustworthy by default.  So every time they generate a new one, this is what happens:

1. Your app says hello to their server
2. Their server sends the newly generated CERT which includes information like: Public key, algorithm, cert valid date range, etc.
3. Your app gets the new CERT and compares it with the old CERT and realizes, oh, these are not the same.
4. Your app says, well, this is not trustworthy and throws an error.

This is by design because this would be similar to the same result of a man-in-the-middle attack. Your client only trusts certain CAs for that reason.  The job of a CA is to certify against certs to see if they are good or bad.  If you can add certs on the fly like that without the CA's knowledge, then the CA really has no idea which certs to trust.

So there could be an intermediate Certificate Authority that this company has opened up to you or that they have worked with to provide to you.  You would have to ask them to see if they are using some kind of CA at all that you could connect to.

I doubt this the case because you said they are using "self-signed" certs which implies that they are not working with any CA.